# Change the size of the button with size of the window in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, button, window

How do I connect the size of any button in the form to the size of the window so that it would change proportionally to the size of the window?

Comment: Are you working with Winforms or WPF?

Comment: You could search for layouts, and docking property, maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Dock and anchor properties on the button should do the trick.
- If all else fails, you could use the Resize event of the window and resize the buttons you'd like accordingly in that event. There's more to be found on this event right here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resize.aspx#Y0

Comment: I'd really advocate the use of `Dock`/`Anchor` and layout containers before using `Resize`.

Comment: Yes you're right, `dock/anchor` is the proper way to try it first.

Comment: There are lots of buttons on the window, using dock is hiding all other buttons.

Comment: Try anchor and AutoSize: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y52cxte(v=vs.80).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171729(v=vs.80).aspx